# Using "echo" when assigning string to a variable failing

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to write a php script that takes a value from database and sets it to a dropdown named gender. I have written the following code:

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        { 
    $gender = $row['gender'];
    $output.= "Gender: <select name='gender'>   
<option value='0' ".if ($gender != 'M' || $gender !='F') { echo ('selected="selected"');}.">Select gender</option> 
<option value='M' ". if ($gender == 'M') { echo ('selected="selected"');}.">Male</option>  
<option value='F' ". if ($gender == 'F') { echo ('selected="selected"');}.">Female</option></select>";
    }
```

I get a server error because of the echo statement(`echo ('selected="selected"')`):

```
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/search.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
```

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Assign the variables before or make a function(s)

Comment: You make them. Ternary probably the cleanest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do just a simple comparison function that returns the select string by comparing two parameters:

```
function selectGender($gender,$out=false)
    {
        // You may not need these 3 lines if $gender is either empty, M, or F //
        $filter = array('M','F');
        if(!in_array($gender,$filter))
            $gender = false;

        if($gender == $out)
            return ' selected="selected"'; 
    }

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    $gender =  $row['gender'];
    $output.= "Gender: <select name='gender'>   
<option value='0'".selectGender($gender).">Select gender</option> 
<option value='M'".selectGender($gender,'M').">Male</option>  
<option value='F'".selectGender($gender,'F').">Female</option></select>";
}
```

Comment: i think there is no need of semi-column in the second line inside the function..

`if(!in_array($gender,$filter));`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the best option here would to just be to remove the source of the problem, make it an if statement:

```
if ($gender != 'M' && $gender != 'F') {
    output .= "...Enter he html with he generic answer selected...";
}
else if ($gender == 'M') {
    output .= "...Enter html with Male selected...";
else {
    output .= "...Enter html with Female selected...";
}
```

It may be a little bulky, but it does the job.

Comment: I did something like this :

`Gender: <select name='gender'>   <option value='0' ".if ($gender != 'M' || $gender !='F') { echo ($selected);}.">Select gender</option>  <option value='M' ". if ($gender == 'M') { echo ($selected);}.">Male</option>   <option value='F' ". if ($gender == 'F') { echo ($selected);}.">Female</option></select>` and assigned `$selected='"selected='selected'"`   Still i get the error....

Comment: You have to assign those portions to variables after $gender.

Comment: Try running the php in a debugger or something similar and see if you get any errors that could give you more help.

Comment: If this doesn't reveal anything, maybe include more context in the question around the area of the error, or do you know for sure that the error is coming from the echo?

Comment: Also note that I used && instead of || in the first if statement, otherwise it will always select he first response.